# Unexpected behavior after scanf() in do..while loop

Tags: c, char, scanf, do-while

Hi I am studying C language by myself.

My question is, is there something I missed which need to know when working with scanf() that takes char value?

To practice do...while loop, I wrote some code like below but it did not work as I expected.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char y_or_n;
    int x =1;
    int y;

    do
    {
            printf("ENTER A NUMBER\n");
            scanf("%d", &y);
            printf("THE NUMBER WILL BE ADDED TO x WHICH IS %d\n", x);
            x = x+y;
            printf("x TURNED INTO %d\n", x);

            printf("KEEP DOING THIS?(y/n)\n");
            scanf(" %s", &y_or_n);
            printf("x is %d\n", x);

    }
    while(y_or_n =='y');

    printf("GOOD BYE\n");

    return 0;
}
```

For the first loop, it worked as I expected.
For example, when I entered 7, x turned into 8. But after scanf() was executed, value of x was changed into 0.
So from second loop, value of x changed temporarily into value of y and changed again into 0.
I guessed that there is something wrong with scanf() function and modified the code slightly: changed type of y_or_n into integer so that scanf() takes integer value.

The modified code is like below

```
include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int y_or_n;
    int x =1;
    int y;

    do
    {
            printf("ENTER A NUMBER\n");
            scanf("%d", &y);
            printf("THE NUMBER WILL BE ADDED TO x WHICH IS %d\n", x);
            x = x+y;
            printf("x TURNED INTO %d\n", x);

            printf("KEEP DOING THIS?(y/n)\n");
            scanf(" %d", &y_or_n);
            printf("x is %d\n", x);

    }
    while(y_or_n ==1);

    printf("GOOD BYE\n");

    return 0;
}
```

This time the code worked as I expected.
Value of x was not changed into 0 even after an execution of scanf() and every time I entered a number that number was added to x.

If my question is not clear, please let me know.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Try inputting 255 or higher value for `y`.

Comment: "is there something I missed which need to know when working with scanf() "  Yes, but that is practically a tautology.  If you are learning C, I strongly encourage you to completely avoid `scanf`.  If you try to use it, you will wind up spending 85% of your time debugging the scanf format language and not actually learning C.  Do not even touch scanf until you have *much* more experience with the language.

Comment: As a practical matter, you must *always* check the value returned by `scanf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` is for reading null-terminated strings, so passing pointer to one-byte buffer for that is bad.

It seems the variable `x` is placed just after the variable `y_or_n` on the memory and writing of terminating null-character by `scanf()` is setting value of `x` to 0.

To read one character, use `%c` instead.

```
char y_or_n;

/* ... */

scanf(" %c", &y_or_n);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I modified the code as you said and it worked.